# Sort a list of objects based on a parameterized attribute of the object

Tags: java-8

Assuming that we have an object with the following attributes:

```
public class MyObject {

    private String attr1;
    private Integer attr2;

    //...

    public String getAttr1() {
        return this.attr1;
    }

    public Integer getAttr2() {
        return this.attr2;
    }
}
```

One way of sorting a list `mylist` of this object, based on its attribute `attr1` is:

```
mylist.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getAttr1));
```

Is it possible to use this code inside a method in a dynamic way and replace the `getAttr1` part with a method that returns the getter of an attribute of the object based on its name? Something like:

```
public void sortListByAttr(List<MyObject> list, String attr) {
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getGetterByAttr(attr)));
}
```

**The `MyObject::getGetterByAttr(attr)` part does not compile**, I wrote it just as an example to explain my idea

I tried to implement a method with the following code `new PropertyDescriptor(attr, MyObject.class).getReadMethod().invoke(new MyObject())` but It's still not possible to call a method with a parameter from the `comparing` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a method like

```
public static Function<MyObject,Object> getGetterByAttr(String s) {
    switch(s) {
        case "attr1": return MyObject::getAttr1;
        case "attr2": return MyObject::getAttr2;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
}
```

to your class, but the returned function is not suitable for `Comparator.comparing`, as it expects a type fulfilling `U extends Comparable<? super U>` and while each of `String` and `Integer` is capable of fulfilling this constraint in an individual invocation, there is no way to declare a generic return type for `getGetterByAttr` to allow both type and be still compatible with the declaration of `comparing`.

An alternative would be a factory for complete `Comparator`s.

```
public static Comparator<MyObject> getComparator(String s) {
    switch(s) {
        case "attr1": return Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getAttr1);
        case "attr2": return Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getAttr2);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
}
```

to be used like

```
public void sortListByAttr(List<MyObject> list, String attr) {
    list.sort(getComparator(attr));
}
```

This has the advantage that it also may support properties whose type is not `Comparable` and requires a custom `Comparator`. Also, more efficient comparators for primitive types (e.g. using `comparingInt`) would be possible.

You may also consider using a `Map` instead of `switch`:

```
private static Map<String,Comparator<MyObject>> COMPARATORS;
static {
    Map<String,Comparator<MyObject>> comparators=new HashMap<>();
    comparators.put("attr1", Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getAttr1));
    comparators.put("attr2", Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getAttr2));
    COMPARATORS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(comparators);
}
public static Comparator<MyObject> getComparator(String s) {
    Comparator<MyObject> comparator = COMPARATORS.get(s);
    if(comparator != null) return comparator;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
}
```

More dynamic is only possible via Reflection, but this would complicate the code, add a lot of potential error source, with only little benefit, considering that you need only to add one line of source code for adding support for another property in either of the examples above. After all, the set of defined properties gets fixed at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

You could also have a single place where this comparators would be defined:

```
 static enum MyObjectComparator {

    ATTR1("attr1", Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getAttr1));

    MyObjectComparator(String attrName, Comparator<MyObject> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.attrName = attrName;
    }

    private final Comparator<MyObject> comparator;

    private final String attrName;

    private static MyObjectComparator[] allValues = MyObjectComparator.values();

    public static Comparator<MyObject> findByValue(String value) {
        return Arrays.stream(allValues)
                .filter(x -> x.attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                .map(x -> x.comparator)
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }

}
```

And your usage would be:

```
public void sortListByAttr(List<MyObject> list, String attr) {
    list.sort(MyObjectComparator.findByValue(attr));
}
```

Comment: first, upvote all. I'd like use an enum to do that too. IF you rename the `findByValue` to `by` I think it is more meaningful.

Comment: @holi-java that's actually a pattern I've seen in lots of projects (the `findBy`), mainly Spring - so I sort of got used to it

Comment: yeah, specifically introduce an enum we can taking more information, make it in OO way. then we can write  something as `sort(by("attr1").comparator)` or `process(by("attr1").getter)`